# How to use specialisation in a sentence

Tags: grammar, nouns

> My specialisations are in the German and English languages.
>
> My specialisations are the German and English languages.

Is "specialisation" here appliable to both of the sentences? Also, Should I use "language" instead of "languages"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are correct, it just comes down to flow and personal preference at this point.

Personally, I would reword the sentence to something like this:

**My language specializations are German and English.**